# Can't get Flixel preloader working via flash IDE

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ide, adobe, flixel

I'm currently trying to work with flixel library via Flash IDE.

Everything is okay except the preloader - it just doesn't work.

I suppose the flash IDE does not support the directive `[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]`, which flixel uses when being compiled in flex builder to create a preloader.

Any way to get the flixel preloader working with ide (without modifying flixel sources)?

UPD: Also, i want to avoid using frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Frame] metdata tag is ignored by the Flash IDE compiler, but all that instruction does is to place all the code with the exception of the Preloader class (in your example, or whatever is the defined 'factoryClass') onto the second frame. Since you have a timeline right there in the Flash IDE, you can put the instantiation of the Preloader class definition into the first frame for yourself, and add the rest of the code onto the second frame. Remember to put a stop on the second frame.

Alternatively, and probably a better solution, is to get a copy of Flash Builder, FDT or Flash Develop, all of which should respect your [Frame] metadata, or can very easily with the right flags.

More information about the [Frame] metadata can be found here: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=946 (which is probably where Flixel got the idea from in the first place). Hope this helps.

Comment: I use FDT to write code, but i like compiling via Flash IDE. I actually thought there would be a way without using frames.

Comment: There's definitely no way to leverage metadata and build in Flash. It's one of the (many, many) disadvantages to building through the IDE. Your choice!

Comment: I see more advantages, than disadvantages in using the IDE to build my  swift.